# Excel vba - find row number where colum data (multiple clauses)

Tags: excel, vba, find, row, where-clause

I need a function in VBA that finds the row number based on 2 where clauses.

Here is the Excel sample:

```
**     A      B      C      D**
  1    id1    day1   val1   xxx
  2    id2    day1   val2   xxx
  3    id3    day1   val3   xxx
  4    id1    day2   val1   xxx
  5    id2    day2   val2   xxx
  6    id3    day2   val3   xxx
```

I need to find the row number (in this case row number is **2**) where B = "day1" and A = "id2".

Based on the row number, I need to further get the values of other columns, i.e. C2, D2

Hope that the question is clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With your data setup like that, you can use the MATCH function to get the row number:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6="id2")*($B$1:$B$6="day1"),),0)
```

If there are no matches for those criteria, the formula will return an #N/A error.  You can also change the criteria to be cell references, for example:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6=F1)*($B$1:$B$6=G1),),0)
```

For the second part of your question, returning values with the found row number, you can use the INDEX function to return a value from a column.  So pretending the Match formula is in cell H1, these two formulas will return the value from column C and D respectively:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$6,H1)
=INDEX($D$1:$D$6,H1)
```

Alternately, you could put it all into a single formula:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6=F1)*($B$1:$B$6=G1),),0))
```

And if you don't want to be looking at errors, you can use an IFERROR on excel 2007+

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6=F1)*($B$1:$B$6=G1),),0)),"No Matches")
```

Error checking for Excel 2003 and below:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6=F1)*($B$1:$B$6=G1),),0)),"No Matches",INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$6=F1)*($B$1:$B$6=G1),),0)))
```

[EDIT]: I am including a VBA solution per user request.  This uses a find loop, which is very efficient and flexible, and shows how to extract values from other columns once a match has been found:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strDay As String

    strID = "id2"
    strDay = "day1"

    Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(strID, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            If LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "B").Text) = LCase(strDay) Then
                'Found a match
                MsgBox "Found a match at: " & rngFound.Row & Chr(10) & _
                       "Value in column C: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "C").Text & Chr(10) & _
                       "Value in column D: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text
            End If
            Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(strID, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this in Excel and it works. I need this to be done using a macro in VBA. How this would be translated into a VBA code (macro)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In VBA you can do a brute force check like the following:

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim message As String
  Dim row As Long
  row = Find("id1", "day2")
  message = "Not Found"
  If (row > 0) Then
    message = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value
  End If
  MsgBox message
End Sub

Function Find(aVal As String, bVal As String) As Long
  Dim maxRow As Long
  Dim row As Long
  maxRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
  For row = 2 To maxRow
    Dim a As String
    a = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value
    b = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value
    If a = aVal And b = bVal Then
      Find = row
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next row
  Find = -1
End Function
```