# Excel VBA Find.Method , searching for 2 Values in a row writing a value

Tags: excel, find, vba

I want to search within a table e.g.

A B C
D E C
A H I
A H C
For the Values

"A" and "C" and then put the Value "Value" into a cell in the rows where both Values have been found.
I am fairly new to the whole topic so i searched first on the web to find pieces of code that could help me.

```
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim SecondAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim MyArr2 As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Row As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim B As Long
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
MyArr = Array("A")
MyArr2 = Array("C")
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F")
    .Offset(0, 27).ClearContents
    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                    Set Rng2 = Rng.EntireRow.Find(What:=MyArr2(I), After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not Row Is Nothing Then
                        SecondAdress = Row.Address
                        Do
                            Rng.Offset(0, 27).Value = "Value"
                            Set Row = .FindNext(Row)

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

It worked for me searching for one value with the .find method, but i struggle to search for the rows that contain both values.
(The Array in case i want to search for more than one value, say all that have at the beginning A Or D and then a C in the third column)

Do you have any idea?
I dont get how i could implemented several loops.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here, the question is pretty similar and you should be able to adapt the solution to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262403/excel-vba-find-row-number-where-colum-data-multiple-clauses

Comment: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, A As String, C As String, v As String
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   A = "A"
   C = "C"
   v = "VALUE"
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, A).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng1 = Range("A1:C" & N)

   For i = 1 To N
      Set rng2 = Intersect(Rows(i), rng1)
      If wf.CountIf(rng2, A) > 0 And wf.CountIf(rng2, C) > 0 Then
         Cells(i, "D") = v
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, unfortunately it tells me here     N = Cells(Rows.Count, A).End(xlUp).Row is a problem,   
A runtime error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: @JohnDoe  This will happen if column **A** is empty.  In my example, I use column **A**, which columns are you using??

Comment: Hi, i actually use columns F and G , filled from F1 to G11, and adapted the code . 
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
Dim num As Long, row As Long, search1 As String, search2 As String, result As String
Dim rotalrng As Range, currentrng As Range, count As WorksheetFunction
Set count = Application.WorksheetFunction
search1 = "a"
search2 = "b"
result = "Yes"
num = Cells(Rows.count, F).End(xlUp).row
Set totalrng = Range("F1:G" & num)
For row = 1 To num
    Set currentrng = Intersect(Rows(row), totalrng)

Comment: If count.CountIf(currentrng, search1) > 0 And count.CountIf(currentrng, search2) > 0 Then
        Cells(row, "H") = result
        End If
Next row
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Advanced filtering would help you identify rows matching your criteria.

Data > Sort & Filter > Advanced

[Microsoft Support - Filter by using advanced criteria](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b)

[image: Advanced Filter]