# Excel INDEX formula with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am trying to fetch a few attributes from my database based on the three criteria shown in the image. How do you pull them based on the three criteria: **ID, Process & Category**.

[image]

I know how to use INDEX formula with MATCH formula. How do you use INDEX formula with multiple criteria?

Comment: Have you considered Advanced Filtering?  What you have set up is very similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32869935/5045578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sample data and extraction table are located at `B1:G28` and `I1:N3` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*

Enter this `FormulaArray` in `L2` and copy till last record then to columns `M` and `N`

*(Enter the* `FormulaArray` *pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see `{` `}` around the formula if entered correctly)*

```
=INDEX( E$1:E$28, MATCH( $I2 & $J2 & $K2, $B$1:$B$28 & $C$1:$C$28 & $D$1:$D$28, 0 ) )
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure for the source of your data table that takes your three parameters and filters the data set coming out of the database.