# Get a Range by filtering an other Range with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As a totally new VBA user (I'm actually not even an Excel user) I can't figure out how to do something that, I think, is really easy to achieve.

**Datas**

Consider a basic sheet with :

```
NAME | AGE | WEIGHT
Fred | 33  |  70
Bob  | 45  |  54
Jef  | 33  |  70
```

**Aim**

What I want is a Range that would contains all rows of that sheet `IF the age==33 AND the WEIGHT==70`. So the expected result is :

```
Fred | 33  |  70
Jef  | 33  |  70
```

**My algorithm (as pseudo-code)**

```
function filterMyRange(srcRange As Range) As Range

  myFinalRange = new Range()

  myWorksheet = Worksheets("worksheetName")
  for each row in myWorksheet.rows{
    age = row.column("AGE").value
    weight = row.column("WEIGHT").value
    if age == 33 AND weight == 77{
      myFinalRange.add(row)
    }
  }
  filterRange = myFinalRange
```

**What I found**

I found several topics to help me to reach my goal :

- [To define if a single row match my expectations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262403/excel-vba-find-row-number-where-colum-data-multiple-clauses)
- [To add items to my returned range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320822/loop-through-cells-and-add-to-a-range)

However, having to do it like this seams overcomplicated and I have the feeling that I'm doing it the wrong way.

**Real situation**

All previous sections were to explain my request. Actually, my real case is something like this :

A first sheet with :

```
worker_name | busy_day  | busy_start_time | busy_end_time
String      | Date      | Date            | Date
Fred        | 20/03/2020| 9:30:00         | 13:00:00
Bob         | 20/03/2020| 14:30:00        | 18:00:00
```

A second sheet with :

```
task_name | task_day  | task_start_time | task_end_time | is_Fred_available | is_Bob_available
String    | Date      | Date            | Date          | Boolean           | Boolean
task_01   | 20/03/2020| 10:30:00        | 11:30:00      | False             | True
```

In that second sheet, I want columns "is_Fred_available " and "is_Bob_available" automatically completed.

To do so, I'm trying to create a function `isWorkerAvailableAt(workerName As String, day As Date, startTime As Date, endTime As Date)`.
To reach that goal, while I like to split my functions, I'm trying to create an other function: `findWorkerBusyTimes_byDay(workerName As String, day As Date)`. It's that function that is supposed to return the "filtered Range".

Actually, I could completely do not split my function `isWorkerAvailableAt` and so get around the problem. As a fan of "several small functions is better than a big one", it hurt's me a little bit but it might be the path.

Comment: [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) perhaps.

Comment: @BigBen If I understand properly `Range.AutoFilter`, that method modify the visibility of cells. This is not my goal. What I want is to put that new range into in a variable. Nothing more.

Comment: You need to loop then. What do you want to do with this range? This might be an XY problem.

Comment: I did had a section to my question ("Real situation") where I do explain why I want to do it.

Comment: Definitely an XY problem then. You probably don't even need VBA to accomplish your task, just a simple formula, probably IF and COUNTIFS.

Comment: I will look a little more to COUNTIFS but it seams to do the trick ! Thanks ! However I'm steal curious. Is there any easy way to achieve what I was trying to do ? Basically a VBA equivalent to a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM mySheet WHERE age=33 AND weight=70`.

Comment: An easy way? Not really, unfortunately. Well define easy. There are multiple ways to do it, but not necessarily easy ones.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help !